# Java Regex: Matching a string with multiple sets of brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out how to write a regex expression that would match 4 sets of brackets containing any number of non-bracket characters.

For example, these should be matched.

```
[hello][world][foo][bar]
[][][][]
```

These should not:

```
[a][b][c]
[a][b][c][d]e
[[a]][b][c][d]
```

If I'm not mistaken, this (below) seems to match one set of brackets and the characters within.

```
\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]
```

I thought that I could extend it to 4 sets by doing the following, but it's not working.

```
[\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]]{4}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for any help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]){4}$");
```

To break that down for you:

```
"^(\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]){4}$"
 ││├─┘├───────┘│├─┘ │  └─ the end of the line.
 │││  │        ││   └─ repeat the capturing group four times.
 │││  │        │└─ a literal "]"
 │││  │        └─ the previous character class zero or more times.
 │││  └─ a character class containing anything but the literals "[" and "]"
 ││└─ a literal "[".
 │└─ start a capturing group.
 └─ the beginning of the string.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'm confused as to when one uses brackets or parentheses. "[^\\\[\\\]]*" = zero or more non-bracket characters, but "(abc){4}" = abc four times. When is one supposed to be used versus the other?

Comment: @Dazarath: the repetition/quantifier operators (`?`, `+`, `*`, `{n,m}`) act on the previous *token*, and capturing groups `(...)` and character classes `[...]` both happen to be tokens.  In fact, it is common to use a capturing group (or *non*-capturing group `(?:...)`) precisely because it creates a token out of a sequence.  So if you want to match the word "foo" any number of times you can't say `foo*` because the previous token is `o`, so you need to say `(foo)*`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to group the chunk that you want to repeat, otherwise it will only match something that repeats the final `]` 4 times:

```
(\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]){4}
```

As James points out below, it looks like you were trying to use `[]` for grouping, instead of `()`. This is likely where your error arose.

Comment: You actually need to drop those extra outer brackets.

Comment: Whoops, copy/paste failure. Fixed.